# make all subdomains access website root files

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain

Here's what I want to do:

- Let's say i have www.mysite.com and it's a complex website with alot of files
- I want to make fr.mysite.com, it.mysite.com, uk.mysite.com to access the file in the root website (ie: fr.mysite.com/jobs.php will actually load mysite.com/jobs.php but in the browser url it will show the link with subdomain).
- I want to build a site with content from multiple countries and I want each country to be accessed with it's code as a subdomain. If I can do that I can then process the url in php and know what country code it's in the url.
- Copying the entire site to each subdomain folder isn't an option.

Let me know if you have any idea on how to do that, I guess it's a .htaccess thingy but I can't figure it out .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ServerAlias` in your `VistualHost` configuration: set it up as single virtual host where all sub-domains point into the same root folder:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias *.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "\path\to\your\site\"
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the most recommended way -- no need to involve URL rewrite here.

Comment: Hi, thx for your response. I tried your code but i get an "Internal Server Error" (like when ur .htaccess is not configure properly). Those 3 dots "..." must be there ? And btw I use a shared hosting at godaddy and I don't have a dedicated IP.

Comment: @Adrian Three dots are representing the rest of possible configuration. It should not be like that in your real config. In any case -- you cannot use this code if hosted on GoDaddy shared hosting plan. 1) Use GoDaddy DNS manager to create additional subdomain. 2) Use their Hosting Control Panel to point any sub-domain into the same folder as main domain (it may be possibly to create subdomains within this Control panel so there will be no need to do #1). Refer to their manuals if you do not know how to use their Control Panel. I do not have hosting there ATM and cannot check it out for you.

Comment: Thx for your help i managed to achieve what I wanted from the hosting Control Panel. Cheers