# Show contents of folder with subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my domain here: example.com it goes to the directory /public_html

If someone visits subdomain1.example.com OR subdomain2.example.com, I want it to show the contents of /public_html just like the regular domain without the subdomain.

If someone visits subdomain1.example.com/login.php, it will show /public_html/login.php

I DO NOT want a redirect.

How can I do this? thanks

**UPDATE**: found the answer here: [make all subdomains access website root files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490512/make-all-subdomains-access-website-root-files)

Comment: when you create sub domain it ask for directory you can set there.

Comment: @urfusion I'm doing it dynamically

Comment: Can you provide the code by which you are creating sub domain.

Comment: This is default behaviour, much like www. subdomain. As long as the DNS points to the server the default will pick it up? So what's it doing?

Comment: @urfusion it's not about creating the subdomains, it's about showing the correct folder/directory with ANY subdomain

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490512/make-all-subdomains-access-website-root-files